# Quanergy’s 3D LiDAR M8-1 sensors driver code reference in Ros kinetic

Tags: lidar, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking driver code for Quanergy’s 3D LiDAR M8-1 sensors in ros kinetic , but couldn't find it the same.

i can only get reference for velodyne (3D Lidar) in github :

https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne

can anybody suggest where i should look for  driver implementation of Quanergy’s 3D LiDAR M8-1 sensors.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270076/quanergy%E2%80%99s-3d-lidar-m8-1-sensors-driver-code-reference-in-ros-kinetic/) by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you contacted Quanergy themselves? According to the datasheet the units come with ROS drivers provided by the manufacturer:

[image: quanergy m8 datasheet]

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on 2017-09-02**:
Thanks for this information  . I will contact them .